# Different scrolling speeds on a JComponent using a single JScrollBar

Tags: java, swing

Can I define different scrolling speeds on a JScrollBar?

For example assume we have an image drawn with height 1000 that does not fit in my frame. Therefore I've created a default `JScrollBar` acting as expected, assuming a `viewport` of height 200:

```
[^]
(*) -> The topmost pixel in the frame has height 0 of the image
 |
 |
 |
 |
[v]

[^]
 |
(*) -> The topmost pixel in the frame has height 200 of the image
 |
 |
 |
[v]

[^]
 |
 |
(*) -> The topmost pixel in the frame has height 400 of the image
 |
 |
[v]
```

Now my question: Can I change this behavior? For example I'd like that it acts in the following way:

```
[^]
(*) -> The topmost pixel in the frame has height 0 of the image!
 |
 |
 |
 |
[v]

[^]
 |
(*) -> The topmost pixel in the frame has height 300 of the image!
 |
 |
 |
[v]

[^]
 |
 |
(*)  -> The topmost pixel in the frame has height 650 of the image!
 |
 |
[v]
```

The scrollbar should still look the same as before, but the individual scrolling speeds change depending on where the knob is on the scrollbar. Ideally I want to define some regions where the scrolling speed stays the same. This question may sounds weird but I need such a mechanism since I'm drawing the component of the `JScrollBar` dynamically and I don't know its exact size in advance. Can this behavior even be implemented in Swing?

Comment: JScrollBar returns min and max value, use this value for scroling increment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override JScrollBar method

```
 public int getUnitIncrement(int direction) {
     int superValue=super.getUnitIncrement(direction);
//define a speedScaleValue is calculated based on value and maximum
     return superValue*speedScaleValue; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that's not exactly what I was looking for. The scroll bar should be moving in the same speed but the actual scrolling speed on the image should be increased/decreased depending on the knob position (like in the picture on my post). So when comparing two scrollbars (the default and my "modification"), both having the knob in the exact same position they should be showing a different viewport. Any idea how to achieve this? Maybe the title of this post was a bit misleading.

Comment: It's more complicated thing. The knob is rendered by ScrollBarUI and it's L&F dependent. Take a look at the protected void setThumbBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) method of BasicScrollBarUI. You cn override it adapting Y

Comment: Thanks for your answer StanislavL. I will check this out.